# laravelcollective/html not finding any of my controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravelcollective

I am getting this error from a login page

```
Action App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LoginController@authenticate not defined. (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/lectureme/resources/views/admin/login.blade.php)
```

I know for certain that this controller exists though, so why is it unable to find it? I have also created a new controller in the controller root and named it `TestController`, and tried routing to that instead, but that was also apparently not found.

Any suggestions for how to get access to the controller? Form code:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'LoginController@authenticate']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('username', 'Username:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('username', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('email', 'Email Address:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Login', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I have also tried `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Have you namespaced your controller properly - assuming you have placed your controller in a `Controllers\Admin` directory it would be: `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin`, I would then guess (because I just direct to the route and not the controller action) that you may need to add that to your action: `['action' => 'Admin\LoginController@authenticate']`

Comment: Namespace was wrong and I accidentally commented out my post route. Put as answer and I'll mark as accepted and correct

Comment: No problem. It's actually something I do from time to time and can be really difficult to spot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you `namespaced` your controller properly. Assuming you have placed your controller in the `App\Http\Controllers\Admin` directory it would be:

`namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin`